# Вопросы с изменениями

Tags: предложение, локализация

Обычно бывает достаточно пару минут позалипать на [основной странице ruSO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) чтобы увидеть подобный баннер:

[image: 1 вопрос с изменениями]

Фраза [является на текущий момент переводом](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40268056?key=69e47484aacb7ba9ee13e0c204dcffd1) оригинального текста:

> $count$ questions with new activity

Отсюда видно, что "activity" это всё же не "изменения", особенно когда после клика по этому баннеру появляется вопрос, у которого написано:

> задан 1 мин. назад

Ключевой момент здесь в слове "задан", а не "изменён" или "ответ дан". Таким образом, "activity" надо всё же переводить иначе.

Comment: А почему тема умерла и надпись все еще старая и неподходящая?

Comment: @Matty можем воскресить :) Только до НГ всё равно вряд ли удастся наблюдать измененный вариант.

Comment: просто режет глаза. Почти уже создала аналогичный вопрос, но решила сначала проверить, нет ли такого же) Хотелось бы надеяться, что эта надпись там не навсегда)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий вариант перевода:

> Новая активность по 1 вопросу

---

**Обновил строки на transifex:**

- one

  > Новая активность в $count$ вопросе
- few/many

  > Новая активность в $count$ вопросах

Comment: Как насчет «_в_ 1 вопросе».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вполне годно, я считаю.

Answer (score 2):

Другой вариант

> N вопросов обновлены

Comment: `N`- мало, возьмем `M`. А если серьёзно, то нет акцента на том, что обновления по вопросам. Как я понимаю, что если появятся 2 ответа для единственного вопроса, то число будет `1`, а не `2`.

Comment: @alexolut  Обновил вариант. Но вообще, на мой взгляд, лучше исходной версии пока нет.

Comment: А как же демократические выборы? :(

Comment: @alexolut [meta-tag:морераторский-беспредел] Сообщество выбирало их предложенных вариантов, среди которых, на момент голосования не было варианта «оставить как есть»! PS Возможно стоит еще варианты рассмотреть, которые устроят всех заинтересованных.

Comment: Получается, чтобы зарубить голосование достаточно опубликовать ответ чуть позже остальных и готово. Помимо этого всё же рекомендую обратить внимание на кол-во голосов у вопроса. Т.е. интерес к теме у сообщества есть. Надо запускать участника в тему и не выпускать пока не проголосует :) Гражданский долг, так сказать, заставить выполнить.

Answer (score 1):

Или такой вариант:

> Новые действия с 1 вопросом

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так:

> Обновления по 1 вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариации на ту же тему:

> Обновления в N вопросах

Comment: Вот этот вариант мне больше всех нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Другой порядок слов с более отражающим действительность смыслом:

> Изменения по 1 вопросу

Answer (score -1):

Оставить как есть. Текущая форма довольно лаконичная. Публикация нового вопроса может быть описана словом «изменения».

Comment: Но тогда "изменения по 1 вопросу", а не так как есть сейчас - "1 вопрос с изменениями", ибо вопрос есть, а изменений в нем нет.

Answer (score -1):

Это сообщение не об изменениях в вопросах, иначе там красовалось бы число намного больше. Это - информация о количестве появившихся вопросов после последнего обновления страницы в браузере пользователя.

> *1 вопрос с изменениями, Новая активность по 1 вопросу, Обновления по 1
>   вопросу, Новые действия с 1 вопросом, Изменения по 1 вопросу*

Примерьте к предложенным вариантам действие: написан комментарий или ответ в теме годичной давности. Это тоже изменения, новая активность, обновление, действие...

Предлагаю **при появлении новых вопросов** писать без витиеватостей, не следуя дословному переводу:

> Новых вопросов - X

Просто, лаконично, понятно.

Comment: Нового - X.....

Comment: Это чрезмерно лаконично (еще короче - Х ) )... Регистрируются новые посетители, публикуются новости, обновляются вопросы...

Comment: Если кто-то дал ответ на вопрос, то новых вопросов нет, есть активность по старому вопросу. Писать "Новых вопросов - Х" некорректно.

Comment: alexolut, активность в старом вопросе я привел для сравнения. Некорректно о новых вопросах писать так, как предлагалось.  Выражения *Новая активность...*, *Обновления...* применимо НЕ ТОЛЬКО к появлению новых вопросов. Возможно, нечетко сформулировал мысль. Подкорректировал ответ

Comment: Система не различает активности по новым вопросам и новым ответам. Есть одно сообщение `$count$ questions with new activity` и вот для него  здесь предлагается выбрать подходящий русский вариант. P.S. Для оповещений не забываете собаку перед ником.

Comment: Да не нужна активность по старым вопросам! Забыли... Слово *активность* применимо НЕ ТОЛЬКО к новым вопросам, оно отражает активность в любой теме. О *подходящих русских вариантах*. Т.е. шаг влево, шаг вправо - расстрел? Только неточные переводы, которые не передают смысл? Неужели нельзя написать по-русски?

Comment: Нет доступного способа отделить ситуацию появления новых вопросов от ситуации обновления по старым вопросам. В любом из этих случаев появляется сообщение вида `$count$ questions with new activity`. Если бы можно было эти ситуации различать - проблемы бы не существовало. Сейчас речь исключительно о локализации одного конкретного сообщения, возникающего при вполне конкретной ситуации, а не о доработке движка сайта, если Вы вдруг так подумали.

Comment: Вы неправильно меня поняли (или я неправильно понимаю). Есть сообщение, которое сигнализирует о появлении новых тем после последнего обновления страницы. *активность*, *обновления* вопроса - неточное определение, т.к. фраза **новая активность в 1 вопросе** говорит о том, что была активность **в каком-то** вопросе, не обязательно в новом. Я не пишу о старых вопросах! Тема моего message - неточность смысла самого предложения.

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. Нет отдельного сообщения о появлении новых тем. Я уже несколько раз об этом написал. Баннер появляется при любых обновлениях в базе вопросов: новый вопрос, новый ответ, изменение вопроса, изменение ответа и т.п. **На все эти события одно и то же сообщение.**

Comment: Понял. Прошу извинить. Раньше понимал так, что сообщение касается только новых вопросов.

Comment: От постинга комментария вопрос не всплывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy как и от изменения по голосам. Перевод в "общее" вроде тоже не апает.

Answer (score -1):

Минималистичный вариант:

> : $count$

:)

Comment: Чего уж там, убрать счетчик вообще и писвть "что-то произошло".

Comment: @alexolut  да ладно вам минусить, это же шутка.

Comment: не хочется заапаную шутку потом в transifex прописывать.

Comment: @alexolut сомневаюсь, что такое случится.

Comment: конечно, из-за минусов :-D